# Compare two date, but in different screen/page always return NaN

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

i was modify an object add key date `notif_sent_at` with value from `new Date()` and store in local storage using JSON.stringify

```
 const assignmentDetail = data.response.details.map(function (item) {
            item['notif_sent_at'] = new Date();
            item['notif_sent'] = false;
            return item
        })
```

and then load with JSON.parse(), i was get object of assignmentDetail

```
  "notif_sent": false,
  "notif_sent_at": "2022-07-07T15:40:11.026Z",
```

when i compare date, my expectation get minutes

```
let today = new Date();
let diffMins = Math.round((((today - target.notif_sent_at) % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
console.log(diffMins)
```

i got NaN

Comment: `new Date(target.notif_sent_at)`. `target.notif_sent_at` is string not Date

Comment: Use `Date.now()` with JSON serializing

Comment: i fix it with `Date.parse(target.notif_sent_at)`

Answer (score 0):

modify object add template literal

```
 target.notif_sent_at = `${new Date()}`;
```

and on compare function parse `Date.parse()`

```
 let today = new Date();
 let diffMins = Math.round((((today - Date.parse(target.notif_sent_at)) % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
```